# jQuery .queue() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

The page in question is right here: http://s289116086.onlinehome.us/lawjournaltv/index.php

I'm 90% of the way there, I'm just assuming there's an error with my syntax. Focus on the blue callout area with "Workers' Compensation" as the title:

Basically, I've created a little slideshow there with the controls at the top and when you click on any of them both the callout and the background are to slide.  As you can see it's working now, but the problem is that I want the new background to slide in over the old one.  I've tried several things including the queue() method, delay(), and adding everything else to the animate() callback with no success (right now the background goes black and then the new image slides in). You guys have never let me down before, so I'm hoping this is an easy fix.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually decided to use .queue within the callback function of .animate() and that seemed to do the trick. I'll leave the link intact for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

for your background, I would suggest you use [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) jQuery plugin...